# Default ringtone on SD CARD: will not find audio

Tags: android, ringtone, sd-card

I've been trying to extend my phone profile app to be able to handle the phone's default ringtone.

When setting my app to use the default ringtone with a system default one, it sets fine. When I try to set a default ringtone which is on /sdcard, the Uri goes in correctly, but when it comes to setting it, it only pulls out the pointer to the devices Settings.System setting which doesn't seem to point to my ringtone media.

Usually, when setting a system default one, it Toast's the name and Uri as it sets, with no issue, but with an external one, says "Unknown ringtone" and the Uri shows us the pointer to the system setting).

I'm using `RingtoneManager.getDefaultType()` to get the Uri, then `setActualDefaultRingtoneUri()` to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Shut off phone debugging by going into `Menu->Settings->Applications->Development`. 
Then uncheck the box.